# Get number of orders made for each hour in a certain year

Tags: mysql, sql

In an e-commerce website, I have a database that contains the following fields:

```
id
date_purchased
...
```

The field `date_purchased` has the current format : `2018-02-14 16:27:37`(year-month-day hours-minutes-seconds)

I would like to get, for the year 2018 for example, ordered by ASC, the number of orders made for each hour.

I can't figure out how to order by a certain year, and count the number of orders made each hour of that year.

Something like :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE (
    SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, [date_purchased]) ASC
) 
GROUP BY year(date_purchased) ASC
```

Comment: is `date_purchased` text or datetime/timestamp field?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza datetime

Comment: You tagged `mysql` but your SQL reads as T-sql (microsoft sql server). Which is it?

Comment: show us some sample data and desire output.

Comment: @JNevill it's mysql, I can't find the equivalent of `DATEPART` in mysql

Comment: is [HOUR()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-hour-function.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following would fulfill your requirements in mysql:

```
  SELECT HOUR(date_purchased) hour_purchased, count(*) hour_Count
  FROM yourtable
  WHERE YEAR(date_purchased) = 2018
  GROUP BY HOUR(date_purchased)
  ORDER BY hour_count DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! I never expected someone to answer it this simply, hats off to you sir.

Comment: Note that `date_purchased BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'` can utilise an index, should one exist